# ssl.SSLError: [SSL: CERTIFICATE_VERIFY_FAILED] certificate verify failed Python

Tags: python, ssl

I want to connect to the IRC, using SSL. I write in `Python 2.7`. However, for the code below:

```
HOST = 'chat.freenode.net'
PORT = 7000
sock = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
code = sock.connect_ex((HOST, PORT))
context = ssl.SSLContext(ssl.PROTOCOL_TLSv1_2)
context.verify_mode = ssl.CERT_REQUIRED
context.load_verify_locations('COMODOECCCertificationAuthority.crt')
secure_sock = context.wrap_socket(sock)
```

PyCharm shows error in line `secure_sock = context.wrap_socket(sock)` what is wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> context.load_verify_locations('COMODOECCCertificationAuthority.crt')

I don't know what is in the file `COMODOECCCertificationAuthority.crt` but it looks like you expecting a certificate signed by Comodo. But, the issuer for the certificate of chat.freenode.net is Let's Encrypt and not Comodo. You can get the chain for example with

```
$ openssl s_client -connect chat.freenode.net:7000
...
Certificate chain
0 s:/CN=cherryh.freenode.net
  i:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
1 s:/C=US/O=Let's Encrypt/CN=Let's Encrypt Authority X3
  i:/O=Digital Signature Trust Co./CN=DST Root CA X3
```

This means the root CA you need to trust is 'DST Root CA X3'. You can download the certificate for this CA [here](https://ssl-tools.net/certificates/dac9024f54d8f6df94935fb1732638ca6ad77c13.pem). If you add this as trusted in `load_verify_locations` it works.

Comment: I opened a `https://freenode.net/` page and exported the certificate using my browser (newest Firefox). Why it didn't work then?

Comment: Besides my question above, when I changed the certificate to one you posted a link to, now I have a new error: `ssl.SSLError: [SSL: TLSV1_ALERT_PROTOCOL_VERSION] tlsv1 alert protocol version (_ssl.c:1754)`

Comment: @yak: A site can use different certificates for different services and freenode is doing this, i.e. using a different certificate for https and for irc. As for the second error: this is a different problem and thus should not be asked in a comment. Please ask a new question where you provide more detail about this problem, including full version of python you use (i.e. 2.7.x) and of openssl (`ssl.OPENSSL_VERSION`).